# Custom TPanel Border

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, tpanel

I can make TPanel Border as Black by disabling "Ctl3D" and TPanel Border Style as "bsSingle" and TPanel BevelKind as "bkNone" and TPanel BevelInner "bvNone". But my need is to make TPanel Border as "Blue" or "Red". The other way is to "Caliing Form Paint Event" but I do not wish to use it.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only way to go is:

1. Study `TCustomPanel.Paint` code in `Vcl.ExtCtrls.pas` and
2. Override it in `TPanel` (class) to tailor it to your requirement;

You may use a *interposer class* in the form unit containing your panel.

Comment: You could make a slightly larger panel behind it, colour that red & show/hide it